# How to disable button in javascript and show message to user about processing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When a button is clicked (in the `clientclick` event), I show a confirmation box to the user, with OK and cancel buttons.

When the OK button is clicked, a `buttonclick` event (on the server-side) fires. I want to disable the button (so that the user cannot double-click on the button) and show a message to the user ("Please wait"). My code is not working.

```js
function validate()
{
    var response = confirm(Proceed)
    if(response)
    {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_Controlplaceholdernameofmaster_btnSave').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to upload a file from an interface. If I use the above code, no error is shown, but the button is not disabled and it does not go to the server side. But my upload control becomes empty.

Page structure:

```
update control
update pannel start
dropdownlist1
dropdownlist2
update pannel end
datepicker
button
```

Comment: can you show us the page source instead of the "page structure" ?

Comment: Have you tried calling a JavaScript function to do the PostBack, while disabling the button via a passed-in reference? You would need to set the buttons Submit behavior to false.